# How do I create database dif / upgrade scripts?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, .net-4.5

We're looking at EF 6.x Code First, empty database at this point, for an upcoming project. So far, we've made a test project or two to get a general feel of how things work.

How do we create a dif script to upgrade the database in a production environment? For example, the production database is v1.0, the code to be deployed is v2.0. How do I create a script to be run on a v1 database to upgrade it to v2?

Answer (score 0):

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: <MigrationName> -TargetMigration: <MigrationName>
```

An alternative way is to use RedGate SQL Compare. In my experience, it works much better than having EF generate the migration script for you, especially when you also have some tables with reference data which needs to be populated. With RedGate SQL/Data Compare you can generate migration scripts for schema and data. That's exactly what you want: DIFF!